# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: se.nackademin.BeachBoysSweden.entities.Book@79da4980 is not a known entity type

Tags: jsf, jpa, eclipselink, glassfish-3

Im working on school assignment but keep getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when trying to save my entity to mysql database. This project uses JPA, EJB, JSF, Glassfish and connection pool.Keep in minde that im new to java web development.

Entity:

```
import javax.inject.Named;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;

import javax.persistence.Table;


@Named
@ConversationScoped
@Entity
@Table(name = "BOOKS")
public class Book implements Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "BOOK_ID")
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)  
        private long bookId;

        @Column(name = "TITLE")
        private String title;

        @Column(name = "AUTHOR")
        private String author;

        @Column(name = "PRICE")
        private int price;

        public Book(){

        }

        public Long getBookId() {
                return bookId;
        }

        public void setBookId(Long bookId) {
                this.bookId = bookId;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
                return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
                this.title = title;
        }

        public String getAuthor() {
                return author;
        }

        public void setAuthor(String author) {
                this.author = author;
        }

        public int getPrice() {
                return price;
        }

        public void setPrice(int price) {
                this.price = price;
        }

}//end class
```

DAO object:

```
import java.util.List;


import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import javax.persistence.Query;



@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class BookDaoBean implements BookDao {


    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager; 


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Book> getBooks() {

        List<Book> matchingBooksList;

        Query query = entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Book s");

        matchingBooksList = query.getResultList(); 

        return matchingBooksList;
    }


    @Override
    public void saveBook(Book book) {

        if(book.getAuthor() != null){


            entityManager.persist(book); 


        }else{

            System.out.println("Book object id is " + book.getBookId());

        }

    }

}//end class
```

Controller:

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.Conversation;
import javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import se.nackademin.BeachBoysSweden.DAO.BookDaoBean;
import se.nackademin.BeachBoysSweden.entities.Book;



@Named
@RequestScoped 
public class BookController {

    @EJB
    private BookDaoBean bookDao;
    @Inject
    private Book book;
    @Inject
    private Conversation conversation; 

    public String enterForm(){
        conversation.begin();
        System.out.print("enter form");
        return "form";
    }

    public String goToConfirmation(){
        return "confirmation";

    }

    public String saveBook(){   
        bookDao.saveBook(book);
        conversation.end();
        return "list";
    }

}
```

persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="book4PersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="JTA">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/__BookPool</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Root case:

```
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object: se.nackademin.BeachBoysSweden.entities.Book@73b9c795 is not a known entity type.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4169)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:440)
    at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:269)
```

Comment: Please consider providing an [SSCCE](http:/www.sscce.org): not only will it make it easier for others to help you, you may find the problem (or at least something) just by writing it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using annotated classes. You have to tell hibernate which files can be scanned for annotations.

```
<persistence-unit name="book4PersistenceUnit"
        transaction-type="JTA">
    <!-- Explicitly define entities in class tags -->
    <class>Book</class>

    <properties>
          <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
          <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: sry but im not using hibernate.

Comment: if autodetection is not really necessary for you, you can explicitly identify which classes are Entities by adding <class>Book</class> in persistence-unit. In case of defining classes explicitly you don't need autodetection property.

Comment: tried adding following line in persistence.xml  <class>se.nackademin.BeachBoysSweden.entities.Book</class>
but issue still  persist :(

Comment: Why do you need those annotations in entity bean? Named, ConversationScoped. Could you please try to remove them and see what happens then?

Comment: If I remove ConversationScoped my bean will be null:ed efter one request from the browser by using the ConversationScoped i can dictated when the conversation begins and when it ends. My school assignment forces me to use @Named, if i did´t i cant inject it to my controller.

Comment: I think your controller should be ConversationScoped, but not the entity bean. In that case your controller is valid for the period of conversation and it has all the instantiated properties, such as bookDao. One more, I see you're injecting Book entity in the controller, but this is not correct. You should create new Book() and save it, or retrieve Book from the database using dao, modify it (if you wish) and save it using dao class.

Comment: Solved issue by adding
@PersistenceContext(type=javax.persistence.PersistenceContextType.EXTENDED)
in my DAO object, more info on this homepage: http://piotrnowicki.com/2012/11/types-of-entitymanagers-application-managed-entitymanager/

Comment: This is cool. You can add your own answer then, because comments are not really visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the class using

```
<class>Book</class>
```

try removing,

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

Ensure you class is deployed in the same jar/ear as your session bean.

Ensure you are using the correct persistence unit.

If you are redeploying, try restarting your Glassfish server, you may have had some issues in undeployment.